# What is the difference between directed inheritance and pattern inheritance?

Tags: pega

In PDN, in the System Architect Essentials II course they have mentioned Dual inheritance is conceptually similar to single inheritance as many programming languages. What is pattern inheritance and directed inheritance? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 6):

Well in Pega PRPC, there are two types of inheritance:

- Directed Inheritance
- Pattern Inheritance

Pattern Inheritance is **Inheritance on naming convention**, where as Directed inheritance is external or advanced inheritance.

*Pattern Inheritance* is given preference above *Directed Inheritance*. As per Pega, if PRPC needs to find RULES (reusable components) which a particular class can use or have access to, first they search through the pattern inheritance. Which is nothing but, the naming convention followed to name a particular RULE in Pega. If PRPC do not find the RULE through the pattern inheritance, it will search the RULE in Directed inheritance.

For example, While naming a RULE in Pega, we use **Org-Sub-Work-ClassName**, This means, ***ClassName*** is inherited from **Org-Sub-Work** class as well as it is part of **Work-Cover-**. If we see the inheritance of this class, This will show as:

```
Short Description        |   Name
                         |
ClassName                |   Org-Sub-Work-ClassName
Work (Default Work Pool) |   Org-Sub-Work
HRServices Namespace     |   Org-Sub
Top Level Class          |   Org
Cover classes            |   Work-Cover-
Work classes             |   Work-
@baseclass               |   @baseclass
```

If PRPC, needs to search for a RULE for **ClassName**, it will first search in **Org-Sub-Work**, if it is not found, then the search will be made in **Org-Sub**, if the RULE is not found there as well, it will search in **Org**. Once, it is not found, PRPC will start searching in **Work-Cover-**; Not found, next match in **Work-**. If not found in **Work-**, it has to be there declared in **@baseclass**, else it will mark it as not present.

Adding to above and to conclude, the above **ClassName** also inherits **Work-Cover-**, However, the point here to note is in Pega, *"There are only classes, NO INTERFACE".* Therefore, you can think **Work-Cover-** of an interface rather than being a normal class. So, we can extend a class and implement an interface.

Answer (score 0):

The descriptions for both strategies can be found [here](https://pdn.pega.com/reuse-and-version-management/how-class-inheritance-works) on PDN

Answer (score 0):

**Direct inheritance** defines behavior of the class and **Pattern inheritance** defines the classes from which we are inheriting the properties. And by doing so, **Pega** supports multiple inheritance.